# How can I run and execute putty command using java?

Tags: java, putty

How can I run and execute putty command using java.  I want the results to be displayed in a console.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Search for telnet or ssh examples over java, some sockets maybe, or some java learning tutorial. Networking tutorial? Hmm what else I can think of down vote of course...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Putty Command](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and run in using the run.execute option in java

Comment: Can I know which putty command?

Comment: I meant the Putty Command line tool, you need to download it so you can use it, its available for download on their page (in the link)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...
Though I'm not sure regarding the output console

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean invoking SSH commands and not running putty directly.
Check out [JSch](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/&ei=jj3IUMSyGtHasgad6oDYAQ&usg=AFQjCNFEETFDy_PvFq6a3L_sqnj_u5o-ZQ&bvm=bv.1354675689,d.Yms) and the simpler [sshj](http://schmizz.net/sshj/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html) using `putty` from command line.

Check section **3.7 The PuTTY command line**

And use it like in java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("putty.exe <options>");
```